# Shrinking/expanding universe?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion

Would anybody tell by simply observation if all the sudden our universe is shrinking...let say 1000 times? Or may be expanding 1000 times.
Our solar system is spiraling toward galactic center singularity. That means time space continuum fabric is getting smaller and smaller as we are getting closer to the event horizon and we are becoming smaller and smaller. Looking towards other galaxies from our prospective, become obvious that the universe is expanding. Is it true?

Comment: I think you're asking if falling into a black hole could give the the impression the universe was expanding because we'd be falling away from the objects outside the black hole. Is that correct or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: Our solar system has completed about 20 orbits of the galaxy and is *not* spiraling in.  Systems much, much closer to the super massive black hole (SMB) near the galaxy's center are also orbiting it normally - no spiraling in.

Comment: Probably your answer would benefit of corrections such as "imagine we are moving towards a center. .....". I, however guess that I got your meaning as John Rennie said.

Comment: I thank all of you for considering my question. Which was, if an absolute system of reference is taken in consideration, then the  absolute size of a planet (or any object for that matter) is depending on its proximity to a   SMB.